# Can somebody suggest me a book on linear algebra including these topics?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I want to cover the following topics of linear agebra:

1. Dual and Double Dual spaces
2. Transpose of linear operator
3. Rational and Jordon forms
4. Triangulisation and Diagonalisation
5. Cyclic Decomposition

Please, somebody suggest an easy and throughly explained book with examples. Currently I have Hoffman and Kunze, This book is very difficult for me.

Please provide the link a .pdf file if available on internet

Comment: I think Serge Lang has all the above, except dual and double dual spaces. I studied a part of his book long ago, and it seemed to have everything. Serge Lang, Linear algebra.

Comment: Most books are not available freely on the internet. For those that aren't, I think you should do the dirty, investigative work yourself.

Comment: Did you meant to write "Jordan form" rather than "Jordon form"?

Answer (score 1):

Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right" is great for those just starting out.